# want to make 5 images with convert ... -graphity

Tags: image, imagemagick, gravity

If i test convert at single command: convert  -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -bordercolor #3CDE1B -border 3 -bordercolor #098606 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -stroke #AD2EC2 -strokewidth 2 -gravity center caption:'1. image text'  1image.jpg

that create the image. But not with the 5 images, with parenthesises:

convert [ -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -bordercolor #3CDE1B -border 3 -bordercolor #098606 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -stroke #AD2EC2 -strokewidth 2 -gravity center caption:'1. image text' ] 1image.jpg [ -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -bordercolor #3CDE1B -border 3 -bordercolor #098606 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -stroke #AD2EC2 -strokewidth 2 -gravity center caption:'2. image text' 2image.jpg ] [ -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -bordercolor #3CDE1B -border 3 -bordercolor #098606 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -stroke #AD2EC2 -strokewidth 2 -gravity center caption:'3 image Text' 3image.jpg ] [ -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -bordercolor #3CDE1B -border 3 -bordercolor #098606 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -stroke #AD2EC2 -strokewidth 2 -gravity center caption:'4 image text' 4image.jpg ] [ -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -bordercolor #3CDE1B -border 3 -bordercolor #098606 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -stroke #AD2EC2 -strokewidth 2 -gravity center caption:'5 image text' ] 5image.jpg

what i have to change?

Thank you for your reading and your time.

The output from my command line, if i test the command with the 5 images:

convert: unable to open image `[': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: no decode delegate for this image format` ' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575.
convert: unable to open image `]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: unable to open image` ]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575. convert: unable to open image` 1image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: unable to open image `1image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: no decode delegate for this image format` ' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575.
convert: unable to open image `2image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: unable to open image` 2image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: unable to open image `]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: unable to open image` ]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575. convert: unable to open image` [': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575. convert: unable to open image` 3image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: unable to open image `3image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: unable to open image` ]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: unable to open image `]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: no decode delegate for this image format` ' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575.
convert: unable to open image `[': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: no decode delegate for this image format` ' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575.
convert: unable to open image `4image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: unable to open image` 4image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: unable to open image `]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: unable to open image` ]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575. convert: unable to open image` [': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575. convert: unable to open image` ]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924.
convert: unable to open image `]': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924. convert: no decode delegate for this image format` ' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575.

I have't a idea, what i have to do, and what i try to do.

Do you have a idea for me?

Thank you for your time, and reading

Comment: Please format your command so it is not all on one line. It is too hard to read. Also show an example of what you want to create.

Comment: If you are trying to add borders to your text image from caption:, then put the border settings and border command AFTER creating the caption: image.

Comment: Imagemagick uses parentheses (), not square brackets [], for processing of images on the side. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis. In Unix, the parentheses must be escaped with \. In Windows, the escape is not needed.

Comment: Please use end of line escapes (^ on Windows and \ on Linux/Mac) to format your text. Also use the <> button after highlighting in this forum to make the commands keep line breaks.  Read how to use the formatting buttons.

Comment: Now, i created a single command that runs: convert  -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -gravity center caption:'1. image text' image1.jpg

Comment: Another one, with the 5 images, don't run:  convert ( -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -gravity center caption:'The Text from the 1. image' ) image1.jpg \ 
 ......
 \ ( -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -gravity center caption:'The Text from the 4 image' image4.jpg ) \
 \ ( -background #FFFFFD -bordercolor #327640 -border 3 -fill #1069CF -font Roboto -size 1200x800 -gravity center caption:'The Text from the 5 image' ) image5.jpg

Comment: convert help: convert [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ...] [options ...] file

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct syntax for your command. Create the text image first, then add the border.  Also use -background XXX for caption:, not -fill XXX.  Use the {} button to format the command in the window.

```
convert -background "#1069CF" -size 1200x800 -font Arial -gravity center caption:'1. image text' -bordercolor "#327640" -border 3 image1.jpg
```

[image]

To make multiple images in the same command, use -write outfileN for each command and use null: at the end

```
convert \
\( -background "#1069CF" -size 1200x800 -font Arial -gravity center caption:'1. image text' \
-bordercolor "#327640" -border 3 -write image1.jpg \) \
\( -background "#1069CF" -size 1200x800 -font Arial -gravity center caption:'1. image text' \
-bordercolor "#327640" -border 3 -write image2.jpg \) \
\( -background "#1069CF" -size 1200x800 -font Arial -gravity center caption:'1. image text' \
-bordercolor "#327640" -border 3 -write image3.jpg \) \
null:
```

What is your OS?  On some Unix systems, you need to quote around the hex colors.  On Windows, the parentheses should not be escaped with \ and the end of line escape is a ^ rather than the .

Comment: @HartmutTheis You can also move all the settings that are common to all your images to immediately after `convert` and they will remain set, then you can omit them later in the parentheses, i.e. `convert -gravity center -size 1200x800 -font Arial ...`

Comment: Thank a lot both fmw42, and Mark Setchell, you help me a lot! 

fmw42, I use osx.

Mark, that is a phantastic idea, with the parenthesis and the remaining!

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that. But I was assuming you wanted each  image to be totally different.

Comment: Yes fmw42, I‘ll make the dimension from the Images different and the Image text, the font and border are the same.

Comment: add `-fill fontcolor` inside your parentheses commands

Comment: @HartmutTheis Please don't forget to accept ✅ Fred's answer, and upvote  if it is useful like you said - that way, Fred's efforts are recognised, and future readers know a) it works and b) there is no need to answer it. Thank you.

Comment: a lot of thank's @fmw42 the colour are changed.

Comment: Is that a question or a confirmation?